# SQL Cross Table Select Issue

Tags: sql

So I'm needing to find the largest difference between 2 dates in a column for all entries that link to a specific pet species, but I am having trouble doing so. I have got the part that finds the difference done, but linking it to the other table is where I am stuck.

```
SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(stayEndDate, stayStartDate))
FROM stay
GROUP BY stayStartDate, stayEndDate 
ORDER BY MAX(DATEDIFF(stayEndDate, stayStartDate)) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Above is the query I have so far to find the largest difference between 2 date columns in a table. In this table is another column called 'petID'. This column is a foreign key of another table called 'pet'. In this other table is a 'species' column. I need my query to only check entries that link to a specific species, but I am not sure how to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated. If I need to provide more info about the tables, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a *cross table select*. It's a simple INNER JOIN with a WHERE clause.

Comment: @KenWhite Could you please help me with doing that? I'm very confused how to implement that into this query I have already.

Comment: It would be much more helpful to you if you tried to take that information and solve the problem yourself. I've always found that getting a hint at how to solve a problem and then figuring it out myself is a much better way to learn than just being handed an answer.

Comment: What you need to solve your problem is to know the SQL basics. Try [sql interactive tutorial](https://sqlbolt.com/). This will help you a lot in the future if you serious about working with SQL.

Comment: I don't get the question.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even see a JOIN in that query. It is a single table query, no? Where is the Pets table?
From your description on other table and column info something like this would work (I assume Pets and Stay are 1-to-many related):

```
SELECT Pets.Species, max(datediff(stay.stayEndDate, stay.stayStartDate)) as maxStay
from Stay
inner join Pets on Stay.PetId = Pets.PetId
group by Pets.Species
ORDER BY MAX(DATEDIFF(stay.stayEndDate, stay.stayStartDate)) DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

You could also add a WHERE clause if you are looking for a single species (then no need for limit, nor the Species column in result).

NOTE: I left the datediff() syntax as you supplied. You didn't tell us the DBMS you are using. Normally a datediff syntax would have a date part component like:

```
datediff( day, startDate, endDate)
```